# Is it possible to have more than one label for a tikz node and use arrows for connecting nodes to labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[border=100pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[circle, shading=ball, drop shadow, ball color=red!10!black, minimum width=4cm, color=white,  opacity=.5, label={[blue]left:A}] (ball1) at (0,0) {BALL 1};

 \node[circle, shading=ball, drop shadow, ball color=red!20!black, minimum width=4cm, color=white, opacity=.5, label={[red]right:B}, xshift=5cm] (ball2) at (2,0) {BALL 2};

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you want to do ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `pin`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use as much labels as you need: just declare several `label` options. But if you want to join label and node with a line/arrow, use `pin`.

```
\documentclass[border=100pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, shading=ball, drop shadow, ball color=red!20!black, 
      minimum width=4cm, color=white, opacity=.5, 
      label={[red]right:B}, 
      label={[blue]135:A},
      pin={45:C}, 
      pin={[pin distance=1cm, pin edge={<-, shorten <= 1pt, red}]below:D}] 
  (ball2) {BALL 2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]