# Quantikz: Annotation Text Above Gate

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, quantikz, qcircuit

For a given gate symbol in the quantikz package, I would like to be able to place text above or below the gate in addition to the gate label.

Shifting the text up and using `\n` to force multiple lines in the gate label results in an error. As [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687412/quantikz-tikz-slice-text-placement) mentioned, the `\gate` command in quantikz is defined in a strange way. Furthermore, I cannot conjure up a way to assign a second label to a single gate (which I would shift independently of the first label).

In particular, I am looking to place text either underneath or above the gate symbol similar to the "0.003" seen here:

[image: Text shows below the gate symbol, which is a box annotated by a single letter within said box.]

Is there a way to use quantikz to automate this for me, or perhaps tikz?

Edit 2 - Here is a minimal working example snippet of code that I tried splitting into two lines with `\n`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\begin{quantikz}
\\
\lstick{$q_0$} & \gate[label style={yshift=0.4cm}]{0.003\n X} & \ctrl{1} & \meter{} \\
\lstick{$q_1$} & & \targ{} & \meter{}
\\
\end{quantikz}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

Ideally the `X` would remain inside the gate, while the 0.003 would go above or below the gate. However, executing this code results in the following image (on my end):
[image]

Update 1 - Was able to sort of achieve the goal by defining the following command in the snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\errgate}{O{}O{2em}O{1.5em}mm}{
\gate[priority label=above,disable auto height,][0][0]{#5}
\gate[][0][0]{#4}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$q_0$} & \errgate{X}{0.001} & \ctrl{1} & \meter{} \\
\lstick{$q_1$} & & \targ{} & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

Issue being that it creates a very long and large box, rather than a neat, small box.

[image: long and large box]

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you please post your code for your screenshot, so that other users will have something compilable to work with when answering you?

Comment: @gz839918 Posted!

Comment: Better yet: make your code snippet a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{centering}
\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$q_0$} & \gate[label style={label={[red]above:$0.001$}}]{X} & \ctrl{1} & \meter{} \\
\lstick{$q_1$} & & \targ{} & \meter{}
\end{quantikz}
\end{centering}
\end{document}
```

[image: red text above gate box]

Just passing a label via the "label style" argument that `\gate` uses is sufficient (referencing the answer used in [this partially related tikz question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317129/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-label-for-a-tikz-node-and-use-arrows-for-co#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20as%20much,line%2Farrow%2C%20use%20pin%20.)).